# Argocd Automatic App Deployment to kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-deployment, argocd

I'm currently testing Argocd for our application deployment in Kubernetes cluster. I would like to know whether the following features are available in Argocd

1. Is there any option in Argocd for creating one group and point it to a cluster.?
2. Feature like automatic deployment is possible in argocd ?

Ideally our intention is once the kubernetes cluster is up, apps will automatically be deployed without any further intervention as long as the app objects have been created in Argo and pointed at a cluster

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. I am not sure what you mean by a group, but grouping can be accomplished with [AppProject CRD](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#projects). So when you create an [Application](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#applications) you can specify to which AppProject it belongs to and that AppProject can be used to define all sorts of constraints, like to which cluster to deploy, which namespaces can be accessed and some more access control stuff.
2. Yes, ArgoCD can monitor a git repository for you (can be a folder in a repo, a branch or a tag) and when it finds differences it will try to sync the cluster state with the new repo changes. And all these can be done automatically, you just need to [configure it like this](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/user-guide/auto_sync/). What is nice is that ArgoCD can even [manage itself](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#manage-argo-cd-using-argo-cd) once that it was applied on the cluster.

For more details about ArgoCD, you can check [their website](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/) and join their [Slack channel](https://argoproj.github.io/community/join-slack) where more specific questions can be addressed. There are a lot of people willing to help there.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding groups, you can also create an [application of applications](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/cluster-bootstrapping/#app-of-apps-pattern), where an Argo "parent" application is created that points to a path in your [repository](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/getting_started/#6-create-an-application-from-a-git-repository) and Argo automatically creates applications for each of the `Application` manifests (yaml files) found at that path.

Regarding automatic deployment, Argo will poll to detect changes to the `Application` manifests in your repository. However, you must make those changes without the help of ArgoCD itself, either manually or automated separately. It does not provide a convenient mechanism for polling a docker registry and automatically updating the Application resource  with the latest version of your application. This is one feature you will miss if migrating from Flux, [which does this](https://docs.fluxcd.io/en/1.18.0/faq.html#how-does-it-automate-deployment).